# Return a JSON string on HTTP request

Tags: php, javascript, ruby-on-rails, windows-phone-7

I am making a WP7 app that needs to get JSON data from an external website. However, I do not want to parse the JSON directly through the app for many reasons, one being that the returned data is not always consistent.

To solve this problem, I want to write my own service in a language I know (JavaScript, PHP, RoR are preferred) to return this data in a consistent format. Instead of sending a request to the original URL, I want to be able to send a request to my service, which will then return the data.

I have no idea how to write such a service that returns up-to-date JSON from the original source. The information keeps changing very second, so I cannot statically render a page and update it every day or whatever. The data must be polled every time a user of my WP7 application wishes to look at it.

Thank you for any guidance.

EDITS for DevZer0:

- `echo $data` just prints `Array`
- `echo json_encode($data)` gives me this:

`{
    "stream": [
        [
            "</td>BeyondTheSummit</td>13751</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</td>WagamamaTV</td>2653</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</td>VeRsuta</td>1566</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</td>dubasTV</td>1128</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</td>followJotM</td>733</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</td>EternaLEnVyy</td>532</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</td>InozemeC</td>448</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</td>liquidkorok</td>295</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</td>DotaTalkStream</td>279</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</td>Sheever</td>260</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</td>Weppas</td>215</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</td>BeyondTheSummit2</td>93</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</td>dota2russia</td>56</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</td>PMSyanyan</td>54</td></tr>"
        ]
    ],
    "vod": [
        [
            "</span></td>GosuCup Asia VII: Zenith vs Dreamz /w ..</td>8</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</span></td>Dota 2 Dire Overlord Announcer Pack (W..</td>301</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</span></td>Dota 2 Purge plays Drow Ranger</td>9348</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</span></td>Typical Mistakes vs eL'Pride BigPoi..</td>1184</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</span></td>Team Empire vs Oslik Gaming BigPoin..</td>1162</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</span></td>Dota 2 Bottom 10 - Ep. 1 (Pilot - Reje..</td>73888</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</span></td>iCCup vs Next kz BigPoint Battle ..</td>631</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</span></td>eL'Pride vs RoX KIS BigPoint Battle..</td>712</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</span></td>Fnatic EU vs Artyk Gaming Game 1 Big..</td>2155</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</span></td>Fnatic EU vs Artyk Gaming Game 2 Big..</td>1668</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</span></td>Fnatic EU vs Lions Pride Bigpoint Ba..</td>988</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</span></td>Artyk Gaming vs iCCup Bigpoint Battl..</td>666</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</span></td>GosuCup Asia VII: Zenith vs Mineski</td>316</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</span></td>Orange eSports' 'Net' - Amazing Rubick..</td>5868</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "</span></td>DotA2 - Outshine Vol.3</td>18672</td></tr>"
        ]
    ],
    "dota2vods": [
        [
            "2w ago</td>Orange vs </span>Rising Stars</td>BO3</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "2w ago</td>KP vs </span>ICCup</td>BO1</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "2w ago</td>KP vs </span>Mouz</td>BO1</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "2w ago</td>Na'Vi vs </span>RoxKiS</td>BO1</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "2w ago</td>Power Rangers vs </span>Alliance</td>BO1</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "2w ago</td>LGD.INT vs </span>Orange</td>BO3</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "2w ago</td>OsG vs </span>Alliance</td>BO1</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "2w ago</td>zRage vs </span>KP</td>BO1</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "2w ago</td>Empire vs </span>Quantic</td>BO1</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "2w ago</td>Empire vs </span>TCM</td>BO1</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "3w ago</td>Empire vs </span>KP</td>BO1</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "3w ago</td>Quantic vs </span>TCM</td>BO1</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "3w ago</td>Empire vs </span>RoxKiS</td>BO1</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "3w ago</td>Mouz vs </span>ICCup</td>BO1</td></tr>"
        ],
        [
            "3w ago</td>4FC vs </span>Mouz</td>BO1</td></tr>"
        ]
    ]
}`

If i copy this raw data into JSONLint, it says the JSON is valid. However, if I put in my URL ("http://blah.com/streams.php"), it says it is invalid. I know that JSONLint can take a URL to validate, not just raw data.

Here's my full PHP file as of now (streams.php):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$url = "http://the-website-with-json";

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

return json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you create intermediate service page that fetches json data from the external website? You can format the json as per your need. Your wp7 app can then request data from the intermediate service page.

Comment: THat is exactly what I am trying to ask. To clarify my question, how do I handle the HTTP request from my WP7 app? How must my service respond to the request?

Comment: I'm still not sure what your are trying to ask. Nonetheless, create a page, example- webservice.php. Copy the code mentioned below by DevZer0, which outputs processed json data. Your wp7 app can simple request webservice.php and parse the data.

Comment: Please look at my latest comment in DevZer0's reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrapper class sounds something like this

```
 function wrapper($data) {
     $json = file_get_contents("http://.......");
     $obj = json_decode($json);

     //process your reconstruction consuming $obj

     return json_encode($obj); //or a new object that you transformed $obj 

 }
```

Then from your main application you can call

```
 $data = wrapper($data);
 $obj = json_decode($data);
```

Comment: I am familiar with encoding/decoding JSON data. That is not my question. Can I render this data in a .php file (in JSON format) and consume it as JSON data in my WP7 application? (As opposed to somehow creating a .json file every second with my PHP script)

Comment: Ok, will try and get back to you.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I'm unable to produce valid JSON when validating at JSONLint.com

Here's what I have:
    `$json = file_get_contents("example.com");
    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    return json_encode($data);`

I used this code to test your method, but JSONLint says the result is invalid. I have also tried `return $json`, with no luck.

Comment: did you set `header("Content-Type: application/json");` when your sending the output

Comment: I've updated my post with my PHP code. Even after setting the content-type as you suggested, the error persists.

Comment: where are you `return[ing] $json` needs to be `echo $json`